# PrestaShop - Reload CMS page with additional parameters

Tags: prestashop

**Situation**: I needed to add form with POST method to CMS page. I created custom hook and a module displaying the form successfully. Then I need to react to user input errors eg. when user doesn't enter email address I need to detect it, display the whole page again together with the form and with "errors" in user input clearly stated.

**Problem**: The problem is to display the WHOLE page again with connected information (eg. about errors etc.). In the module PHP file when I add this kind of code,

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'modulename.tpl');
```

it (naturally) displays ONLY the form, not the whole CMS page with the form.

In case of this code,

```
Tools::redirectLink('cms.php?id_cms=7');
```

I can't get to transfer any information by GET neither POST method.

```
$_POST['test'] = 1;
Tools::redirectLink('cms.php?id_cms=7&test');
```

I tried to assign to smarty variables too

```
$smarty->assign('test', '1');
```

(I need to use it in .tpl file where the form itself is created) but no way to get it work.

```
{if isset($test)}...,
{if isset($smarty.post.test)}...,
{if isset($_POST['test'])}... {* neither of these conditionals end up as true *}
```

Even assigning a GET parameter to url has no impact, because there is link rewriting to some kind of friendly url I guess, no matter I included other argument or not. (`[SHOPNAME]/cms.php?id_cms=7&test` -> `[SHOPNAME]/content/7-cmspage-name`)

**My question is**: is there a way to "redirect" or "reload" current page (or possibly any page generally) in prestashop together with my own data included?

I kind of explained the whole case so I'm open to hear a better overall solution than my (maybe I'm thinking about the case in a wrong way at all). This would be other possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use javascript to validate the form - you can use jQuery to highlight the fields that are in error; providing visual feedback on how the submission failed. In effect you don't allow the user to submit the form (and thus leave the page) until you're happy that the action will succeed. I assume that you will then redirect to another page once a successful submission has been received.

There's lots of articles and how-tos available for using javascript, and indeed jQuery for form validation. If you want to keep the site lean and mean, then you can provide an override for the CMS controller and only enqueue the script for the specific page(s) you want to use form validation on.

If the validation is complex, then you might be best using AJAX and just reloading the form section of your page via a call to your module. Hooks aren't great for this kind of thing, so you might want to consider using an alternative mnethod to inject your code onto the cms page. I've written a few articles on this alternative approach which can be found on my [prestashop blog](http://www.ecartservice.net/prestashop-articles/1-4-plugins-revisited-part-1/)